# How to print all strings from the list specified number of times using nested loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find a way to print all items from the list at once and repeat that operation specified number of times using nested loop. At the end I need to print statement "MAKE IT STOP"

```
lyrics = ["I wanna be your endgame", "I wanna be your first string",
      "I wanna be your A-Team", "I wanna be your endgame, endgame"]
lines_of_sanity = 6

for item in lyrics:
counter = 1
while counter <= lines_of_sanity:
    print(item)
    counter += 4

print("MAKE IT STOP")
```

I need to find the code that will print the lyrics. It should keep repeating each line one-by-one until you've reached lines_of_sanity lines. Then, it should keep going to finish out the current verse. After that, print "MAKE IT STOP"
It should print:

```
I wanna be your endgame
I wanna be your first string
I wanna be your A-Team
I wanna be your endgame, endgame
I wanna be your endgame
I wanna be your first string
I wanna be your A-Team
I wanna be your endgame, endgame
MAKE IT STOP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reverse the order of loops:

```
while counter <= lines_of_sanity:
  for item in lyrics:
    print(item)
  counter += 1
print("MAKE IT STOP")
```

if you want  the lyrics seperated by space instead of new lines, then replace:

```
print(item)
```

with:

```
print(item,end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in one loop if you calculate before-hand how many times you want to it to print and also use the `join` function.

```
from math import ceil

lyrics = ["I wanna be your endgame", "I wanna be your first string",
      "I wanna be your A-Team", "I wanna be your endgame, endgame"]
lines_of_sanity = 6

for _ in range(ceil(lines_of_sanity / len(lyrics))):
    print('\n'.join(lyrics))

print("MAKE IT STOP")
```

Comment: Thank you :) It works well! It was not the way they expect me to do, but as long as the code do what it has to do it's fine :)

Comment: @romero2827 No problem. If this answer solved your question, make sure to accept it for future viewers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers